# ExtJS: HTMLEditor loses content on Accordion re-expand

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an accordion panel with typical settings. In each of the panels there used to be a `textarea` and everything worked fine.

Now I replaced each `textarea` with an `htmleditor`. When I collapse a panel and re-expand it, the content of the `htmleditor` is lost. This didn't happen when I used `textarea`. How to solve this problem?

Edited: also, when re-expanded, the `htmleditor` freezes, and I can't input anything. But the buttons work (bold, insert link, switch to source editing, etc). What's more strange, when I toggle 'switch to source' button *twice*, the content reappears, in a different font!

Using the `Accordion`:

```
myDataStore.load({params: ...}, callback: onLoadSuccess);
......

onLoadSuccess: function() {
    // for each data item, create a new panel and add it to myListPanel
    for (var i = 0; i < myDataStore.getTotalCount(); i++) {
        var dataItem = myDataStore.getAt(i);
        var newFormPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
            labelAlign: 'top',
            items : [{
                xtype: 'htmleditor',
                fieldLabel: 'Content',
                autoScroll: true,
                enableFont: false,
                enableLists: false,
                value: dataItem.get('content');
            }],
            buttons: [{...}]
        });
        // add this panel to the accordion
        myListPanel.add({
            title: 'Another panel',
            items: [newFormPanel]
        });
    }
    myListPanel.doLayout();
}
```

Current `Accordion` config:

```
var myListPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    autoHeight : true,
    autoWidth: true,
    autoScroll : true,
    layout : 'accordion',
    layoutConfig : {
        titleCollapse: true,
        animate: true,
        fill : false,
        autoWidth: true,
        hideCollapseTool: true,
    },
});
```

Comment: Could you post your full working code?

Comment: Full code would be too long... I updated the usage of `Accordion`: new panels are added to the accordion panel from a data store.

Comment: UPDATE: I turned `animate` to `false` and the problem solved! @_@

Answer (score 0):

For me a `htmleditor` does not lose the content when collapsing and expanding it.

However, one solution would be to listen for the `collapse` event and store the current editor content to a property. 
On the `expand` event, you place it again in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem with a collapsible border layout under ExtJS 6.2.2.

I nailed it down to the point where the HtmlEditor looses its content:

[Ext.dom.Element.slideIn()](https://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-slideIn) -> [Ext.dom.Element.wrap()](https://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-wrap) -> [Ext.dom.Element.appendChild()](https://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-appendChild) -> line `me.dom.appendChild(el)` ([description of appendChild() on developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild?retiredLocale=de#description))

The iframe content of the HtmlEditor will be lost after the DOM of the HtmlEditor has been moved to the animation wrapper. It seems, that generally after reparenting DOM nodes having an iframe somewhere in their children loose its iframe-content.

A simple solution is to set `animCollapse: false` and `floatable: false` in panel config, e.g.:

```
}, {
    region: 'east',
    xtype: 'ip_tasks_descriptionremarkspanel', // own 'form'
    width: 980,
    split: true,
    collapsible: true,
    collapsed: true,
    animCollapse: false, // <---------
    floatable: false // <---------
}, {
```

If you want to use the floatable feature (`floatable: true`), you have to use the following override (see lines with `added` comment):

```
Ext.override(Ext.panel.Panel, {
    floatCollapsedPanel: function() {
        var me = this,
            placeholder = me.placeholder,
            splitter = me.splitter,
            phBox = Ext.util.Region.from(placeholder.getBox(false, true)),
            floatCls = Ext.panel.Panel.floatCls,
            collapsed = me.collapsed,
            layoutOwner = me.ownerCt || me,
            slideDirection, myBox,
            hoverlisteners = {
                mouseleave: me.onMouseLeaveFloated,
                mouseenter: me.onMouseEnterFloated,
                scope: me,
                destroyable: true
            };
        if (me.isSliding) {
            return;
        }
        // Already floated
        if (me.el.hasCls(floatCls)) {
            me.slideOutFloatedPanel();
            return;
        }
        me.isSliding = true;
        // Lay out in fully expanded mode to ensure we are at the correct size, and collect our expanded box
        placeholder.el.hide();
        placeholder.hidden = true;
        me.el.show();
        me.setHiddenState(false);
        me.collapsed = false;
        layoutOwner.updateLayout();
        // Then go back immediately to collapsed state from which to initiate the float into view.
        placeholder.el.show();
        placeholder.hidden = false;
        me.el.hide();
        me.setHiddenState(true);
        me.collapsed = collapsed;
        layoutOwner.updateLayout();
        myBox = me.getBox(false, true);
        if (me.fireEvent('beginfloat', me) === false) {
            return;
        }
        me.slideOutTask = me.slideOutTask || new Ext.util.DelayedTask(me.slideOutFloatedPanel, me);
        // Tap/mousedown/mousemove outside the floated element, its placeholder, or its splitter slides it back.
        me.pointerLeaveListener = Ext.getDoc().on({
            mousedown: me.onFloatedPointerEvent,
            mousemove: me.onFloatedPointerEvent,
            scope: me,
            destroyable: true
        });
        if (!me.placeholderListener) {
            me.placeholderListener = placeholder.on({
                resize: me.onPlaceholderResize,
                scope: me,
                destroyable: true
            });
        }
        me.phHoverListeners = placeholder.el.on(hoverlisteners);
        me.elHoverListeners = me.el.on(hoverlisteners);
        me.el.addCls(floatCls);
        me.floated = collapsed;
        // Hide collapse tool in header if there is one (we might be headerless)
        if (me.collapseTool) {
            me.collapseTool.el.hide();
        }
        if (splitter) {
            phBox = phBox.union(splitter.getBox(false, true));
        }
        switch (me.collapsed) {
            case 'top':
                me.width = phBox.width;
                me.setLocalXY(myBox.x, myBox.y + phBox.height);
                break;
            case 'right':
                me.height = phBox.height;
                me.setLocalXY(myBox.x - phBox.width, myBox.y);
                break;
            case 'bottom':
                me.width = phBox.width;
                me.setLocalXY(myBox.x, myBox.y - phBox.height);
                break;
            case 'left':
                me.height = phBox.height;
                me.setLocalXY(myBox.x + phBox.width, myBox.y);
                break;
        }
        slideDirection = me.convertCollapseDir(me.collapsed);
        // Remember how we are really collapsed so we can restore it, but also so we can
        // become a layoutRoot while we are floated:
        me.floatedFromCollapse = me.collapsed;
        me.collapsed = false;
        me.setHiddenState(false);
        if (me.animCollapse) { // added
        me.el.slideIn(slideDirection, {
            preserveScroll: true,
            duration: Ext.Number.from(me.animCollapse, Ext.fx.Anim.prototype.duration),
            listeners: {
                afteranimate: function() {
                    me.isSliding = false;
                    me.fireEvent('endfloat', me);
                    me.fireEvent('float', me);
                }
            }
        });
        } else { // added
            me.el.show(); // added
            me.isSliding = false; // added
            me.fireEvent('endfloat', me); // added
            me.fireEvent('float', me); // added
        } // added
    },
    privates: {
        slideOutFloatedPanel: function(preventAnimate) {
            var me = this,
                compEl = me.el,
                collapseDirection, focusTarget,
                afterSlideOut = function() {
                    me.slideOutFloatedPanelEnd();
                    // this would be in slideOutFloatedPanelEnd except that the only other
                    // caller removes this cls later
                    me.el.removeCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'border-region-slide-in');
                    // Event fired when floated stateus ends
                    me.fireEvent('endfloat', me);
                };
            if (me.isSliding || me.destroyed) {
                return;
            }
            me.isSliding = true;
            me.floated = false;
            me.slideOutFloatedPanelBegin();
            if (preventAnimate) {
                compEl.hide();
                return afterSlideOut();
            }
            if (typeof me.collapsed === 'string') {
                collapseDirection = me.convertCollapseDir(me.collapsed);
            }
            me.fireEvent('beginfloat', me);
            if (me.animCollapse) { // added
            compEl.slideOut(collapseDirection, {
                preserveScroll: true,
                duration: Ext.Number.from(me.animCollapse, Ext.fx.Anim.prototype.duration),
                listeners: {
                    afteranimate: afterSlideOut
                }
            });
            } else { // added
                compEl.hide(); // added
                afterSlideOut(); // added
            } // added
            // Focus the placeholder which should delegate into itself
            if (this.containsFocus) {
                focusTarget = this.findFocusTarget();
                if (focusTarget) {
                    focusTarget.focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Edit:

I encountered another point where the HtmlEditor looses its content. If you use a border layout, a currently floated panel isn't considered as a layout item and causes a `Ext.layout.container.Container.moveItem(item, target, pos)` during refreshing layouts:

`Ext.layout.container.Container.renderChildren()` -> `me.renderItems(items, target)` -> `!me.isValidParent(item, target, pos)` -> `me.moveItem(item, target, pos)`

The following override will fix this:

```
Ext.override(Ext.layout.container.Border, {
    getLayoutItems: function() {
        var owner = this.owner,
            ownerItems = (owner && owner.items && owner.items.items) || [],
            length = ownerItems.length,
            items = [],
            i = 0,
            ownerItem, placeholderFor;
        for (; i < length; i++) {
            ownerItem = ownerItems[i];
            placeholderFor = ownerItem.placeholderFor;
            // There are a couple of scenarios where we do NOT want an item to
            // be included in the layout items:
            //
            // 1. If the item is floated. This can happen when a region's header
            // is clicked to "float" the item, then another region's header or
            // is clicked quickly before the first floated region has had a
            // chance to slide out. When this happens, the second click triggers
            // a layout, the purpose of which is to determine what the size of the 
            // second region will be after it is floated, so it can be animated
            // to that size. In this case the existing floated item should not be
            // included in the layout items because it will not be visible once
            // it's slideout animation has completed.
            //
            // 2. If the item is a placeholder for a panel that is currently
            // being expanded. Similar to scenario 1, a second layout can be
            // triggered by another panel being expanded/collapsed/floated before
            // the first panel has finished it's expand animation. If this is the
            // case we do not want the placeholder to be included in the layout
            // items because it will not be once the panel has finished expanding.
            //
            // If the component is hidden, we need none of these shenanigans
            //if (ownerItem.hidden || ((!ownerItem.floated || ownerItem.isCollapsingOrExpanding === 2) && !(placeholderFor && placeholderFor.isCollapsingOrExpanding === 2))) { // removed
            if (ownerItem.hidden || ownerItem.floated || ((!ownerItem.floated || ownerItem.isCollapsingOrExpanding === 2) && !(placeholderFor && placeholderFor.isCollapsingOrExpanding === 2))) { // added "ownerItem.floated || "
                items.push(ownerItem);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
});
```